# Facing difficulty in moving the two id's

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

By means of `<?php echo $productlist->productid;?>` in href i am passing the productid,its fine based on that i can able to display the items.
The url is looking like this when i am passing like this **http://localhost/sample/index.php/userlogin/items/35**    .

```
<ul class="left_menu">
                <li class="odd"><a href="<?php echo  BASE_INDEX_URL;?>/userlogin/items/<?php echo $productlist->productid;?>">
                        <?php 
                         echo $productlist->productname;
                        ?>
                    </a></li>
</ul>
```

My model is taking the value like this

```
public function items($productid=0)
    {
    }
```

But i want to pass one more id as categoryid in the href, how can i do that

My model is taking the value like this(for 2 parameters)

```
  public function items($productid=0,$categoryid=0)
    {

    }
```

Comment: just make a simple test in your url add fake categoryid you url will be like http://localhost/sample/index.php/userlogin/items/35/1 and check your function is taking category id or not, if not then set routing

Comment: http://localhost/shoppingcart/index.php/userlogin/items/37&27 url values are going like this but getting the error like "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Comment: yes you will get error because & char is not allowed in url just send your ids slash separated 37/27 will work or in config file you have to allow & in config file search for permitted_uri_chars

Comment: if we use slash means it will take that as url like www.test.com/category/products => www.test.com/27/37

Comment: common you can send chars also you just need to encode using encoders like urlencode and others you can find in online.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this .........Write a JavaScript function in the file which takes two arguments product id and category id. In the href call that JavaScript function and pass two arguments in php. In the JavaScript function which you will write down in the file use

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/controller_name/function_name_in_the_controller/" +product_id +'/'+category_id ;
```

In the write a function with name you will assign in the the above url and pass two arguments. Get those two id's using in that function and save it in an array and pass that array if you want to use it in an view........

```
    public function ($product_id,$category_id) {

      $product_id = $product_id;
      $category_id = $category_id;
```

}

Comment: how to get those ids in  function pls explain that also

Comment: In which function the function which you write in view file or controller file........If it is in controller file you can directly access.........

Comment: Yes in controller, if i directly means how can the code recognise that this is productid , this is categoryid